# filter pandas column only for string containing rows

Tags: string, pandas, filter

I end up with a pandas dataframe that looks like this after I read and filter a excel file.

```
Col1    Col2
afaf    abc 1
1512        
asda    cdd 2
adsd
```

I am trying to end up with

```
Col1    Col2
afaf    abc1
asda    cdd2
```

I tried `df['Col2'].replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)` and to do a `dropna` afterwards but nothing gets replaced, So I think that it can't replace because column2 has more than one space in those empty rows.

I forgot to mention that I can't use strip because the Col2 string has spaces that I need to keep unchanged.

Any ideas?

Comment: So basically filter out the rows where there's nothing in Col2 or something like that?

Comment: yeah that would be the expected result :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with condition for remove some possible whitespaces by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then check if `length` by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) is not `0`:

```
print (df[df.Col2.str.strip().str.len() != 0])
   Col1   Col2
0  afaf  abc 1
2  asda  cdd 2
```

If no whitespaces:

```
df[df.Col2.str.len() != 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can strip the column using pandas [str.strip()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) function. this should remove all the whitespace.

It could look like this

```
df['Col2'].str.strip().replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
```

So using [pipe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) you can receive the non nan rows as

```
df.iloc[df.pipe(lambda x:x['Col2'].str.strip().replace('',np.nan)).dropna().index]
```

This latter, updated solution, also works under your additional whitespace constraints. However, note that I used pipe before that constraint was posted.

Now, I'd choose e.g. a solutions like Jezrael's, but formulated as

```
df[df['Col2'].str.strip() !='']
```

I think, this is a little bit clearer than using the len functions

Just performed some benchmarks on a really small dataframe. PirSquared solutions is fastest, followed by Jezrael's, followed by my solution using comparison to ''. Last place is the piping variant.

Answer (score 2):

use `str.match`

```
df[~df.Col2.str.match(r'^\s*$')]
```

[image]